# foreach repeat html structure after every nth for attachment

Tags: php, images

I am trying to achieve result with below structure in foreach loop where after every two images it will repeat entire structure.

I have some basic knowledge for something I can use eg. counter++; and than %2 but don't know syntax and how to use it for my code.

```
<?php
    function dt_attached($postid=0, $size='thumbnail', $attributes='', $linksize='full', $count=-1) {
        if ($postid<1) $postid = get_the_ID();
        if ($images = get_children(array(
            'post_parent' => $postid,
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => $count,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))

            foreach($images as $image) {
                $attachment=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'thumbnail');
                $small_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'midium');
                $big_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'full');
                ?>

                <div class="mainrow">

                    <div class="block">
                        <a href='<?php echo $big_image[0]; ?>' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' title='Thumbnail 1' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $small_image[0]; ?>' ">
                            <img src="<?php echo $attachment[0]; ?>" <?php echo $attributes; ?> />
                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <!--[I want to get two images in mainrow]-->
                    <div class="block">
                        <a href='<?php echo $big_image[0]; ?>' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' title='Thumbnail 1' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $small_image[0]; ?>' ">
                            <img src="<?php echo $attachment[0]; ?>" <?php echo $attributes; ?> />
                        </a>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <?php //the_attachment_link($image->ID, false, true, false); ?>
        <?php }
    }
?>
```

So what I want is if there is more than two images it will repeat entire html structure. Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Are you willing to show only two images in one row?

Comment: Yes I will show only two images per row. (two block per row) I want two block per row even one is empty to prevent breaking the layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok, basicly.
you need this logic

```
<?php
  if (($a % 2) == 1)
  { echo "$a is odd." ;}
  if (($a % 2) == 0)
  { echo "$a is even." ;}
?>
```

you'll loop like you do. 
but indeed keep a counter. and check accordingly. I changed your code without testing.

```
    <?php
    function dt_attached($postid=0, $size='thumbnail', $attributes='', $linksize='full', $count=-1) {
        if ($postid<1) $postid = get_the_ID();
        if ($images = get_children(array(
            'post_parent' => $postid,
            'post_type' => 'attachment',
            'numberposts' => $count,
            'post_mime_type' => 'image',)))

    //declare some counter var
       $counter = 0;

            foreach($images as $image) {
                $attachment=wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'thumbnail');
                $small_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'midium');
                $big_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image->ID, 'full');
               // everytime raise your counter + 1
                $counter=  $counter+1; //you can use  $counter+=1; also 
                ?>
    // this part you only want every 2 rows 
<?php       
if (( $counter % 2) == 1){
 if ($counter > 1) {
  $uneven = true;     
      echo '</div>' ; // your closing div
}
   echo '<div class="mainrow">'; // opening div
 }

    //this part you want every time so no need to check it 
    ?>
                    <div class="block">
                        <a href='<?php echo $big_image[0]; ?>' class='cloud-zoom-gallery' title='Thumbnail 1' rel="useZoom: 'zoom1', smallImage: '<?php echo $small_image[0]; ?>' ">
                            <img src="<?php echo $attachment[0]; ?>" <?php echo $attributes; ?> />
                        </a>
                    </div> <?php
  if ($uneven && $counter == count($images)){ // $count is your amount of attach ?>
                    <div class="block">
                       <!--your empty image code -->
                        </a>
                    </div> <?php } ?>

</div>
     <?php }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: I have tried this but the issue is it is not adding another block for the row if there is only one image. Means if there are three images than first row will have two block but second row will have only one block which is breaking my layout. I want two blocks per mainrow even if there is only one image for that row.

Comment: That is not clear in your question thou.
The solution is easy thou, at the end of your loop you can check if you are even or uneven. If your count is uneven it means you had only one in your last row and you can add another subblock with some empty image then. I will edit above code for your convenience, do change your initial question so this is clear thou..

Comment: I really appreciate your effort and help but I am not damn expert so getting trouble to understand what you have described here. I would appreciate if you can write few lines of code same as above you done.

Comment: @pixelngrain if so you can wrap the foreach loop into `div` with style (display: block;) that'll not break layout.

Comment: I edited the code. mind any syntax errors I haven't run the code. What happensi is you check if you are at the end, if you are at the end of your loop and you are at un eneven image it means there is only one and you can print an empty block.

Comment: @amit, your idea is nice but I am using responsive layout and it will limit my layout if I will set width and height with display: block. or you are talking without defining width and height only diplay block will work?

Comment: @woony, thanks a lot let me try this code and get back to you with the result. I really really appreciate lot your effort. Thanks again.

Comment: @woony, the code is repeating mainrow in bad way. I need to check more

Comment: Its bit difficult for me but I will now continue without adding extra div if there is odd number. So I am selecting your answer and vote it. Thanks a lot

Comment: ok, I just typed the code without testing. So if you can't figure it out. Let me know, and I will test it proparly.